# std::function does not work, but plain old function pointer does - why?

Tags: c++, pointers, std, function-pointers, std-function

I want to make a function that will take `std::function` as a parameter, and inside call that passed function:

```
void handleCollision(std::function<void(const Entity&)>& resolveCollision, const Entity& block) {
    if (playerInRangeOf(block) && playerIntersects(block)) {
        resolveCollision(block);
    }
}
```

And the caller (within the same Class):

```
for (auto&& block : blocks) {
    handleCollision(resolveCollisionAxisX, block);
}
```

Error:

```
Reference to non-static member function must be called
error: no matching function for call to 'StateGame::handleCollision(<unresolved overloaded function type>, Block&)'
handleCollision(resolveCollisionAxisX, block);
                                            ^
```

---

**However**, if I follow with C-style function pointers:

```
void handleCollision(void (StateGame::*resolveCollision)(const Entity&), const Entity& block) {
    if (playerInRangeOf(block) && playerIntersects(block)) {
        (this->*resolveCollision)(block);
    }
}
```

Then it does work fine (caller is the same).

How can I make the `std::function` work? Side note: I don't want to make anything static.

Comment: **Poor question:** You have an error on `block` and you don't let us know what is block. If you want help, then make sure that your question has no missing information and no superfluous information as both make us waste time. In fact, it look like the error is on `resolveCollisionAxisX`but the compiler show it at the wrong place. Still we don't have that declaration. Neverthless someone has guessed that you try to directly initialize a `std::function` with a member function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in a lambda, replace

```
handleCollision(resolveCollisionAxisX, block)
```

to

```
[this](const Entity& e){
   this->resolveCollisionAxisX(e);
}
```

Also replace `std::function<void(const Entity&)>&` to `std::function<void(const Entity&)>` or `const std::function<void(const Entity&)>&`

Comment: Writing out `self->` is redundant. `[this](const Entity& e){
   resolveCollisionAxisX(e);
}` works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

C++ member functions are plain C function with the addition of the instance address as the first parameter.

For instance, `void StateGame::resolveCollisionAxisX(const Entity&)` for the compiler is equivalent to
`void resolveCollisionAxisX(StateGame* instance, const Entity&)`

Here a small code snippet showing a working example. See how the `std::function` template parameter is `void(A*)` and not just `void()`.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <functional>

struct A{
  void foo1(void(A::*resolveCollision)(void)){
    std::cout << "foo [c-style]" << std::endl;
    (this->*resolveCollision)();
  }

  void foo2(std::function<void(A*)> resolveCollision) {
    std::cout << "foo [std::function]" << std::endl;
    resolveCollision(this);
  }

  void target() {
    std::cout << "resolve" << std::endl;
  }

  void caller() {
    std::cout << "caller" << std::endl;
    foo1(&A::target);
    foo2(&A::target);
  }
};

int main() {
  A a;
  a.caller();
}
```

If you know Python, there it is more explicit this concept, in fact, all member functions have `self` as first parameter (which is the alter ego of `this` in C++).